# parse error: Unexpected EOF

Tags: php, eof, parse-error

I have an error. it says:

> syntax error, unexpected end of file

```
<?php
{
if($_POST["submit']) {
    $recipient=\"youremail@gmail.com\";
    $subject=\"Inquiry Form\";
    $sender=$_POST [name];
    $senderEmail=$_POST [email];
    $FeedbackQuestion=$_POST [feedback];

$mailBody=\"Name: $name\nEmail:$email\n\n$feedback;

\mail($recipient, $subject, $mailbody, \"From: $name<$email>\");

$thankYou=\"Thank you! Your message has been sent.\";

} 
?>
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Please post your error code and take a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: There are plenty of IDEs available for PHP like Eclipse, Netbeans. These editors show you the error right at code level.

Comment: Also, in the question itself, while block below `if`is showing syntax highlighted. Why didn't you get your error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 2):

replace `if($_POST["submit']) {` with `if($_POST["submit"]) {`

see the different `"` instead of `'` after `submit`

And then, remove the first `{` at line 2.

The complete correct code is:

```
<?php
if($_POST["submit"])
{
    $recipient="youremail@gmail.com";
    $subject="Inquiry Form";
    $sender=$_POST ['name'];
    $senderEmail=$_POST ['email'];
    $FeedbackQuestion=$_POST ['feedback'];

    $mailBody="Name: $name\nEmail:$email\n\n$feedback";

    mail($recipient, $subject, $mailbody, "From: $name<$email>");

    $thankYou="Thank you! Your message has been sent.";
}
?>
```

Also all the `\"` must be replaced with " because the `\"` is needed only inside strings enclosed by `"`.

Also, the arrays keys must be enclosed by `'`.